# Exibir aviso quando a página for aberta no Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como fazer o alerta abaixo ser exibido quando a página for aberta no navegador Mozilla Firefox

```
alert("Alguns elementos desta página podem não ser exibidos no Firefox. Para evitar problemas, utilize o Google Chrome. Atenciosamente - Designed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
                alert("Alguns elementos desta página podem não ser exibidos no Firefox. Para evitar problemas, utilize o Google Chrome. Atenciosamente - Designed");

        }
```